# Find convergence and limit of $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{-x^2}-(1+ax^2)}{x^4}$

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence, exponential-function

I have an exercise of finding a  real number "a" and limit of
 $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{-x^2}-(1+ax^2)}{x^4}$$

I have no idea what should I do, can someone help me solve this step-by-step?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lhôpital-rule-or-series-expansion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Use the fact that$$e^{-x^2}=1-x^2+\frac{x^4}2-\frac{x^6}{3!}+\cdots$$

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But how should I apply that?

Comment: You should apply it in order to show that there is one and only one $a$ for which that limit exists: $a=-1$.